# Why does CGPathRelease cause memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I try to release a path it will cause a memory leak that is about 5 megabytes big. Every time i call CGreleasePath the ram memory usage will increase again by 5 megabytes. What could be the reason that is causing this memory leak?

This is the code where all my paths are getting used:

```
    //viewcontroller.h
        CGMutablePathRef path;

        //viewcontroller.m

        -(void)viewDidLoad{
    path = CGPathCreateMutable;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(movement1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(motor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    -(void)movement1{
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, greentmporary.x, greentmporary.y);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, greenpoint1.x, greenpoint1.y);
    }

    -(void)motor{
CGPathRef thickpath = NULL;
    thickpath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path, NULL, (6+bigsizeYellow), kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineJoinMiter, 0);

            if (CGPathContainsPoint(thickpath, NULL, greenpoint1, NO) && krockamedgreen == NO) {
                NSLog(@"YES");
[self reset]
    }

          if (CGPathContainsPoint(thickpath, NULL, point1, NO) && krockamedgreen == NO) {
                NSLog(@"YES");
[self reset]
    }

         if (thickpath) {
                CFRelease(thickpath);
                thickpath = NULL;
            }

    }

-(void)reset{
    path = NULL;
}
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
//start again
{
path = CGPathCreateMutable;
}
```

Comment: I'd wager your problem rests elsewhere. Have you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu)? And, when you say it "leaks" is this being reported by the "Leaks" tool in "Instruments"? Or just looking at "Live Bytes"? Tell us how you know that the `CGPathRef` is actually the source of the problem. If you're still having problems after ensuring that there are zero warnings in the static analyzer, please update your question with code sample.

Comment: Okey found out the problem. It I allocated bytes for a bitmap type *void using malloc that i didn't free. Weird through running xcode tells me that its problem with the cgpaths.

Comment: You don't release `path` in `-reset` method, just set it to `NULL`.